# Disprove : $\varnothing$ from a non-empty set to a non-empty set is a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> **Counter-example :** Take $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}.$ Then under $\varnothing$, the element $1$ of $A$ does not have an image in $B$. Thus $\varnothing : A \to B$ is not a function.

I seek feedback about my approach whether it is right or wrong.

I know that $\varnothing$ is a function when $A$ is empty. Otherwise it is not.
I have gone through [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45625/why-is-an-empty-function-considered-a-function) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789123/why-is-there-no-function-with-a-nonempty-domain-and-an-empty-range?rq=1), it helped me to understand the cases when $A$ is empty and when $B$ is empty but $A$ is non-empty.

**EDIT :** The definition of function that I am using is as follows,

> A relation $F$ from a set $A$ to set $B$ is said to be a function if and only if-
>
> 1. For every $x \in A$, $\exists y \in B$ such that $(x,y) \in F$,
> 2. If $(x,y) \in F$ and $(x,z) \in F$, then $y=z$.

Comment: I see no problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title can be read two ways.  One is that $\emptyset: A \to B$ is not always a function when $A,B$ are non-empty.  Your example proves that.  Another is that $\emptyset: A \to B$ is never a function when $A,B$ are non-empty.  One example cannot prove that.  You would then have to argue along the lines of "Take $a \in A$, which we can do because $A$ is non-empty.  There is no ordered pair in $F$ with $a$ as a first element, so it fails criterion $1$."

Comment: Yes yes. I actually was also thinking now that I just disproved that "$\varnothing : A \to B$ is a function" by taking counter-example. Thanks.