# Function with domain is the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i have a small question but I can't make up my mind.

If we are given a function $f : X \to Y$

Because a function is in fact a set of ordered pairs, if we take $X$ to be the empty-set, we then say that $f$ does not exist or we say that it is equal to empty-set ? And more general, can you explain me the difference if any between "empty set" and "non-existence" ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, the empty set is a set, whereas non-existence is a concept.

Comment: An example might help: if $X$ is non-empty, and $Y$ is empty, then there does not exist a function $f:X\to Y$. On the other hand, if $X$ is empty, then there *does* exist a function $f:X\to Y$. It's just that the only such function is $\varnothing$.

Comment: @Joe: Hi, in your  first example, why there does not exist a function, I think the function can be also the ∅ set, right ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: Nope. The domain of $\varnothing$ is $\varnothing$, and in my first example, $X$ is non-empty.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789123/why-is-there-no-function-with-a-nonempty-domain-and-an-empty-range/789411#789411) answer for further details.

Comment: @Joe: hmm, as for me, a function is a set of well-ordered pairs that satisfy the uniqueness requirement. In this case, if $X$ is non-empty and $Y$ is empty, all the pairs in the empty-set satisfy the uniqueness requirement vaccously.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: You are missing the "existence of images" requirement (the "uniqueness of images" requirement does indeed hold vacuously). If $X$ is non-empty, then $\varnothing$ is not a function from $X$ to $\varnothing$ because it is *not* true that for all $x\in X$, there is a $y\in\varnothing$ such that $(x,y)\in\varnothing$. In other words, there is an $x\in X$ such that for all $y\in\varnothing$, we have $(x,y)\not\in\varnothing$. Proof: since $X$ is non-empty, it contains an element, say $x_0$. Note that for all $y\in\varnothing$, we have $(x_0,y)\not\in\varnothing$.

Comment: That final statement was vacuous, of course. More generally, if $X$ is non-empty, then there is no function $X\to\varnothing$. You can reason as follows: a function $f$ from $X$ to $\varnothing$ would be a subset of $X\times\varnothing=\varnothing$, and so we must have $f=\varnothing$. But, as we just showed, $\varnothing$ is *not* a function from $X$ to $\varnothing$. (However, $\varnothing$ is a function, and for every set $Y$, it is a function $\varnothing\to Y$). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Joe: Yes, many thanks!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: No problem. I'm glad I could help. I think what might have been confusing you to begin with is this: if there does not exist an object with a property $P$, then the set of objects with the property $P$ equals $\varnothing$. This is a completely different assertion to saying that $\varnothing$ satisfies the property $P$. In the latter case, *there is* an object with the property $P$, namely $\varnothing$, and so the set of objects satisfying $P$ is non-empty.